# How to use bitwise operator with unsigned char data type?

Tags: c++, clang, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bitwise-or

Consider the following code:

```cpp
uint8_t a = 0xFF;
uint64_t b = a << 8u | 0xFFu;
```

I'm getting the following message at line 2, column 14.

> Clang-Tidy: Use of a signed integer operand with a binary bitwise operator

It's not an error it's just a warning I think.

Variable `a` is a `uint8_t` that is the same as `unsigned char`. The same thing occurs if variable `a` is `uint16_t`. However, if variable `a` is `uint32_t`, then it's fine. Is this correct or I'm missing something? Why bitwise operator should only be used with `uint32_t` data type?

How to use bitwise operator in this case? Should I use `static_cast<uint32_t>(a)`?

Comment: It is unclear what your intentions are; if you expect an `uint64_t` to come out of the operation then you should probably cast `a` to `uint64_t`.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in clang-tidy: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36961 .  Maybe you just need to upgrade?